# how to set date to input field using another date input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have two input fields **fromDate** and **toDate**(both are date).I am using datepicker for input field fromDate. toDate is readonly and is dependent on the fromDate.That is date of toDate is is 6+.For example,if fromDate is 11/30/2014 then toDate is 12/6/2014.

My jsp code is

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control dpd1" id="fromDate" name="fromDate">
    <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control dpd2" id="toDate" name="toDate" readonly/>
```

and js code is:`$('.dpd1').datepicker();`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery and change(). In change, You can get the value of `fromDate` and with [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object create new value for the `toDate` input.

```
$(function() {
    $('#fromDate').change(function() {
        var fromDateValue = $(this).val();
        var toDateValue = new Date();

        // some operations

        $('#toDate').val(yourToDate);
    });
})
```

You can add 6 days with this:

```
var today = new Date();
var todayplus6days= new Date(today);
todayplus6days.setDate(today.getDate()+6);
```

**UPDATE:**

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8dx0sLey/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('#fromDate').change(function() {
        var fromDateValue = $(this).val();
        var toDateValue = new Date(fromDateValue);

        toDateValue.setDate(toDateValue.getDate()+6);

        var sDate = toDateValue.getFullYear() + '-' + (toDateValue.getMonth()+1) + '-' + toDateValue.getDate();

        $('#toDate').val(sDate);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jazi. It worked for me only with double digits (days and month more than 9) but not with single digits. So 1 January 2023 gave a format error. To fix it I changed the var sDate to: 

var sDate = toDateValue.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + toDateValue.getMonth() + 1).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + toDateValue.getDate()).slice(-2);

So forcing a double digit for months and days. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this.

```
 $("#from").datepicker({
        onClose: function (selectedDate, instance) {
            if (selectedDate != '') { //added this to fix the issue
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 6);
                console.log(selectedDate, date);
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using input type date:

---

http://jsfiddle.net/washington_guedes/dafbz0qo/

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#fromDate").on("blur", function(){

        var year = parseInt( $(this).val().substring(0,4) );
        var month = parseInt( $(this).val().substring(5,7) );
        var day = parseInt( $(this).val().substring(9,11) );

        month += 6;
        if( month > 12){
            month %= 12;
            year++;
        }

        $("#toDate").val(year + "-" +
              ((month<10)?"0":"") + 
              month + "-" + 
              ((day<10)?"0":"") + day);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
$('#fromDate').datepicker();
$('#fromDate').change(function(){
    var toDate = new Date($(this).val());
    toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()+6);
    month  = toDate.getMonth()+ 1;
    year = toDate.getFullYear();
    $('#toDate').val(month+'/'+toDate.getDate()+'/'+year );
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tegos/9fxk24y7/2/)